# Sonar with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sonarqube

I am trying to setup Sonar 3.6 and/or 3.6.2 with SQL Server 2008. For testing in preparation of conversion from MySql to SQL Server. I am getting no errors when running:

```
sonar.sh console
```

Console Output:

```
Running sonar...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2013-07-31 11:41:12.374:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.6.11.v20130520
jvm 1    | JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
jvm 1    | gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
jvm 1    | 2013-07-31 11:41:43.963:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/alm/sonar-3.6.2/war/sonar-server/},file:/alm/sonar-3.6.2/war/sonar-server
jvm 1    | 2013-07-31 11:41:44.034:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:29000
```

I am running my database on a remote server.  This should not be a problem though.

I am able to access the server with the same credentials with DBVisualizer, so I would imagine it should go through with sonar.

The driver I am using is the one bundled with sonar.

The error that I am getting is web based when I try and access the server.

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

Please try back in a few minutes and contact support if the problem persists.

<%= link_to "Go back to the homepage", home_path %>
```

When I use the h2 embedded database I have no problem accessing it, so I deduce that this is most likely a problem with my database setup.

```
---------------------------------------------------------
# WEB SETTINGS - STANDALONE MODE ONLY
# These settings are ignored when the war file is deployed to a Java EE server.
#---------------------------------------------------------
# Listen host/port and context path (for example / or /sonar). Default values are  0.0.0.0:9000/.
sonar.web.host:                           localhost
sonar.web.port:                           9500
sonar.web.context:                        /sonar

# Log HTTP requests. Deactivated by default.
#sonar.web.jettyRequestLogs: ../../logs/jetty-yyyy_mm_dd.request.log
#sonar.web.jetty.threads.min:              5
#sonar.web.jetty.threads.max:              50

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#
# IMPORTANT : the embedded database H2 is used by default.
# It is recommended for tests only. Please use an external database
# for production environment (MySQL, Oracle, Postgresql, SQLServer)
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#----- Credentials
# Permissions to create tables and indexes must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
sonar.jdbc.username:                       sonar
sonar.jdbc.password:                       sonar

#----- Embedded database H2
# Note : it does not accept connections from remote hosts, so the
# sonar server and the maven plugin must be executed on the same host.

# Comment the following line to deactivate the default embedded database.
#sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:19092/sonar
#sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                org.h2.Driver

# directory containing H2 database files. By default it's the /data directory in the sonar installation.
#sonar.embeddedDatabase.dataDir:/alm/sonar/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/data
# H2 embedded database server listening port, defaults to 9092
#sonar.embeddedDatabase.port:               19092
...
... 
#----- Microsoft SQLServer
# The Jtds open source driver is available in extensions/jdbc-driver/mssql. More details on http://jtds.sourceforge.net
sonar.jdbc.url                             
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://(REMOTE IP ADDRESS);instance=MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=SONAR;selectMethod=cursor;

# Optional properties
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

The sonar username that I have has all permissions for the SONAR database.

I am probably missing something small any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:

The problem is I needed to create a sonar schema, and associate the sonar user to it for the sonar database.

I also ensured that the sonar user had the permissions that it needed in order to create the database.  Started up perfectly.